# Applying formula to rows in pandas recursively,the value has to fetched from above row

Tags: python, pandas

**Input**
df1

```
Initial value=8 
Id rating Learnrate formula
1    2        0.1      7.4  
2    3        0.2      6.52
3    4        0.1
```

For 1st row

```
formula=Initial value*(1-Learnrate)+rating*Learnrate
=8*(1-0.1)+2*0.1=7.2+0.2=7.4
```

For 2nd row onwards
Take previous row formula value=7.4

```
=7.4*(1-0.2)+3*0.2=6.52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the first row (as you did in your question) and loop through the rest of the rows to calculate each formula using previous row's value.

```
#calculate the first row using formula and initial value
df1.loc[0, 'formula'] = Initial value*(1-df1.loc[0, 'Learnrate'])+df1.loc[0, 'rating']*df1.loc[0, 'Learnrate']

#Loop through rows and calculate each formula for row i value using previous value of formula in row i-1
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    df1.loc[i, 'formula'] = df1.loc[i-1, 'formula']*(1-df1.loc[i, 'Learnrate'])+df1.loc[i, 'rating']*df1.loc[i, 'Learnrate']
```

Comment: Code-only answers, though they can solve the question in hand, are less helpful for the community without an explanation of the solution provided. Consider improving your answer by describing the suggestion you have. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you for note. I will edit the post to include more explanation.

Comment: Is there any other method for achieving this without using for loop @Ehsan

Comment: @raj I do not know any other solution rather than solving your recursive function for a closed form solution (which in this case is doable but in general it might not be depending on recursive function). A closed form solution can probably be calculated without a loop but might be computationally costlier since you are not reusing the previous calculations.

Comment: I found df.apply function but how to get previous row value